# Триггер для двух БД MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, триггер, mysql-workbench

Есть простая задача: при внесении новой строки в таблицу одной базы данных, вставлять ту же строку в таблицу другой базы.

Был написан запрос:...

```
delimiter //
create trigger test after insert on bd1.test1 for each row 
begin 
insert into bd2.test2 set test2.first_1 = NEW.test1.first_1;
                            set test2.second_1 = NEW.test1.second_1;
                            set test2.third_1 = NEW.test1.third_1;
end//
```

... но в таком случае возникает ошибка 1046(no db selected). Если перед названиями столбцов уточнить базу, в которой они находятся, то система ругается на unexpected точку.

Подскажите, как реализовать необходимый запрос?@

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ой, нет. Простите за эту оплошность)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER test 
AFTER INSERT 
ON bd1.test1 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bd2.test2 
    SET bd2.test2.first_1  = NEW.first_1,
        bd2.test2.second_1 = NEW.second_1,
        bd2.test2.third_1  = NEW.third_1;
```

И переопределять DELIMITER не требуется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Та же самая ошибка: no db selected (

Comment: Всё работает. См. скриншот. Возможно, Вы не сделали `USE bd1` перед созданием триггера?

Comment: Да, действительно. Совсем из головы вылетело, что базу переключить надо. Спасибо большое))